# Create bearer authorization header in Kotlin Using OkHttp

Tags: api, rest, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

I use OkHttp3 in Kotlin as a HTTP client and send Authorization Token Bearer header in request and return the result.
this is my code, but when run it the app closed :

> RetrofitInstance.kt

```
class OAuthInterceptor(
private val tokenType: String,
private val acceessToken: String,
private val branchid : Int,
private val currency : Int,):Interceptor {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response 
{
    var request = chain.request()
    request = request.newBuilder()
        .addHeader("Authorization", "$tokenType $acceessToken")
        .addHeader("branchId", "$branchid")
        .addHeader("currencyId", "$currency")
        .build()

    return chain.proceed(request)
  }
}

class RetrofitInstance {

companion object {

    private val client =  OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(OAuthInterceptor(
            "Bearer",
            "YourToken",
            123,
            1)
        )
        .build()

    val BASE_URL = "https://url"

    fun getRetrofitInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .build()
    }
}
```

}

> AlbumService.Kt

```
interface AlbumService {
    @GET("users")
    suspend fun getAlbums() : Response<Albums>
}
```

> Album.kt

```
class Albums : ArrayList<dataapi>()
```

> AlbumItem.kt

```
data class dataapi(
    @SerializedName("address")
    val address: String,
)
```

Comment: What error you got in logcat?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kenshi.retrofitdemo, PID: 11387
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)

Comment: i got this error

Comment: The error is because of json parsing. Response is successful. But it could not parse into particular object. Please update json response and model object in question.  Bearer token must be working correctly

Comment: Could you please update your code ,which you do to request api now and model class.